# Recognize borders of each stone on the photo

Tags: c++, image-processing, image-recognition

**My Question**: How can I recognize borders of each stone on the photo below? Size calculation will be an easy task.

First of all I have to tell you that I’m a new kid in image recognition, and I’ll be thankful for any:

- propositions
- useful links
- book titles an chapters in it
- algorithm
- framework(especially C++)
- etc.

So..

I have an image with small stones. And I have to measure their sizes(in pixels at firs).

[image]

I’ve already played with RGB values of any pixel, and highlighted  pixels witch RGB values are between constants defined by me. I don't like that some stones are glued, and some borders are wider that it should be.

```
for (y=0; y<height; y++,pixelIndex = width*y<<2)
    for (x=0; x<width; x++,pixelIndex+=4)
        if (pixelsData[pixelIndex  ]>self.minRedSlider.integerValue && pixelsData[pixelIndex  ]<self.maxRedSlider.integerValue &&
            pixelsData[pixelIndex+1]>self.minGreenSlider.integerValue && pixelsData[pixelIndex+1]<self.maxGreenSlider.integerValue &&
            pixelsData[pixelIndex+2]>self.minBlueSlider.integerValue && pixelsData[pixelIndex+2]<self.maxBlueSlider.integerValue) {
            resultData[pixelIndex] = 255;
            resultData[pixelIndex+1] = 255;
            resultData[pixelIndex+2] = 255;
        } else {
            resultData[pixelIndex] = 0;
            resultData[pixelIndex+1] = 0;
            resultData[pixelIndex+2] = 0;
        }
```

This is how my test app looks like at the moment:

[image]

PS:
I know that my question is very vague, But I have to start and can't find or guess an appropriate direction. Any way, thanks for time you've already spent on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just play with RGB values to find the objects (superpixels). What you try to do is called watersheds segmentation. I recommend to use OpenCV library, they give an example similar to your case [HERE](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) .

Also, there are many algorithm implementations on github.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try and let you know about results.